# Не срабатывает одновременно 2 анимации

Tags: html, css

На нижнем блоке анимация при наведении срабатывает поочередно. Как сделать единовременную анимацию?

[Ссылка](http://atomr-web.github.io/)

```css
.article {
  height: 250px;
}
.left-clm {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease;
  -o-transition: .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: .4s ease;
  transition: .4s ease;
}
.left-clm:hover {
  border-radius: 1000px;
  /* Срабатывает вторым */
}
.left-clm i {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 110px;
  top: 110px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 38px;
}
.left-clm img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease;
  -o-transition: .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: .4s ease;
  transition: .4s ease;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left-clm img:hover {
  margin-top: -90px;
  /* Срабатывает первым */
  opacity: .3;
}
.left-clm a:hover i {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article class="barbershop">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col lg-12">
      <div class="left-clm">
        <a href="/barbershop" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
          <img src="https://rawgit.com/atomr-web/atomr-web.github.io/master/img/screen-barbershop.png" alt="barbershop">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: событие наведения на картинку и на блок - два разных события. попробуйте как-то так например `.left-clm:hover img {margin-top: -90px;}`

Comment: @lexxl срабатывает также, к сожалению

Comment: у меня свежий файрфокс и ваш код срабатывает одновременно. и исправьте ваш код, т.к. путь к картинке локальный, невозможно проверить

Comment: @lexxl извините за глупый вопрос, но сделать не локальный путь? в лисе да, работает, не проверил заранее

Comment: путь к картинку у вас `img/screen-barbershop.png` - мы эту картинку не видим. желательно в примеры вставлять путь из интернетов (http://...). уточните, в каком браузере не работает, ибо наугад никто помочь не сможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вы назначаете начальное состояние `border-radius: 10px;` картинке, а изменяете его на родительском блоке.

Во-вторых, вы навешиваете два события `:hover`, когда можно обойтись одним: оставив его только на родительском элементе.

В третьих, подобное поведение можно исправить с помощью следующего кода:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Полный пример:

```css
.article {
  height: 250px;
}
.left-clm {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: .4s easet;
  -o-transition: .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: .4s ease;
  transition: .4s ease;
  /* Исправляем дерганную анимацию */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
}
.left-clm:hover {
  border-radius: 1000px;
}
.left-clm i {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 110px;
  top: 110px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 38px;
}
.left-clm img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease;
  -o-transition: .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: .4s ease;
  transition: .4s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left-clm:hover img {
  margin-top: -90px;
  opacity: .3;
}
.left-clm:hover a i {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article class="barbershop">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col lg-12">
      <div class="left-clm">
        <a href="/barbershop" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
          <img src="https://rawgit.com/atomr-web/atomr-web.github.io/master/img/screen-barbershop.png" alt="barbershop">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

Основано на ответе к вопросу:
[Webkit border-radius and overflow bug when using any animation/transition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681137/2486051)